# TypeScript: No error when checking an union type

Tags: typescript

We have a function:

```
const fun = (): string => "hey";
```

We have an union type:

```
type Fruit = "banana" | "orange" | "apple";
```

The TS compiler won't allow this:

```
const check = (fruit: Fruit) => {
    if (fruit === "mango") {
        ...        ^^^^^ This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'Fruit' and '"mango"' have no overlap.
    }
}
```

But it does allow this:

```
const check = (fruit: Fruit) => {
    if (fruit === fun()) {
        ...       
    }
}
```

My question is why?

Comment: Not sure I'm following. We have the return type of `fun`, `string` and the type of `fruit`, `Fruit`. I expect this to give an error straight away :?

Comment: `typeof fruit` is `string`

Comment: @Tushar - Thanks. Somehow I managed to **completely miss** the return type annotation, so I assumed its return type was `"hey"` (even though it wouldn't be even without the return type annotation) and went down a rabbit hole. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The return type of `fun` is `string`. You're allowed to use `===` (and `!==`) to compare a `string` operand with a string literal operand, so `fruit === fun()` is perfectly valid. (It's important that it is, since it's part of how you write a type guard.)

But `"mango"` is a compile-time constant value that's definitely not a member of `Fruit`, so TypeScript is warning you proactively that the comparison is pointless; it'll never be true.

You'd get the same error if `fun`'s return type were `"hey"` rather than `string`:

```typescript
const fun1 = (): string => "hey";
const fun2 = (): "hey" => "hey";

type Fruit = "banana" | "orange" | "apple";

const check0 = (fruit: Fruit) => {
    if (fruit === "mango") {
        // ^−−− This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'Fruit' and '"mango"' have no overlap.(2367)
    }
};

const check1 = (fruit: Fruit) => {
    if (fruit === fun1()) {
        // ^−− works
    }
};

const check2 = (fruit: Fruit) => {
    if (fruit === fun2()) {
        // ^−−− This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'Fruit' and '"hey"' have no overlap.(2367)
    }
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzARhgXhgCgJQC4bQBOAlmAOboB8MARABYCmAnjQNwCwAUKJLImACZ0WPLUYsqY5my5coTAA4MYAMUIJisDDQBGAQzAG9NGAB9aIQgbIMT5mnoUKANrY6cuPaDGCNgAawAGYUw4dU18NQ0obEkAby4YJJhiOCww6PQ0bQBbaxAaWITOZNKYAHpymAA9QCQiepgAFTpiCB9wABNNYnAYAHdiZ2cYPWc+vSY2wgYoBEIwGAByOFGIBkWCUmBlKEYYeSU2xajNDYMOpZo88gKNuj0AN2UwEBgQJ8JnRwA6TAEAZgAbAB2bCJZIAXy4EPcnnA3l8DACqAwoXCUEi6NiaGoxVKqXS6KyGH4yBwRXBZQqVTqtX6ln8EEpMChnBhsm48NgiICQlRGQiqix8WZBLRmWyJKQAnJMDxVOpNXqdOarXaYC6UB6CwGQxGYwmUxmcwWy1W602YG2+z2BwYRxOUDOGsu4hod0ez1e7wYnx+fyBoOZrPZnCAA)

Comment: Thank you. I understand the logic behind this but it still seems counter intuitive. I guess I would need to use enums to achieve what I want.

Comment: @tdranv - It was an interesting question. :-) Re enums -- I hate to say it, and I could be wrong, but I suspect you'll find you have the same problem with them: [string enum](https://tsplay.dev/WoDygw), [numeric enum](https://tsplay.dev/mqEarm)

Comment: What I was looking for is to know that something *cannot* be something (i.e., a `fruit` cannot be compared with `fun()` that returns a string. It can only be one of 3 possible values (that are strings themselves...)). Thanks for the thorough answer anyway.